# Eclipse remote developement

Tags: java, eclipse, development-environment

I have a J2EE web application. I'm coding it with Eclipse.
Currently I have Eclipse program and my repositery on my own computer.
I would like to put the repositery on a distant server to develop without to have the code physically on my own computer.
The idea is to launch Eclipse from my compture to connect on the distant repositery and to compile and deploy ON the server and not on my computer.

Does Eclipse RSE provide these fonctionnality ? It seems to fetch the code through the network to compile the application.

(An alternative would be to have Eclipse on the remote server and export display on my computer (with X server)...)

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://eclipse.org/che/

Comment: Maybe :) But I don't really understand where is the source code with this solution

Answer (score 1):

I think Eclipse IDE RSE plugin only helps to edit the remote Java files from your PC. Rest compile/build/deploy has to be done in the remote system only.

Comment: How do you tell at Eclipse to deploy on the distant server ? Thanks